# Iterate through a json object based on the value of an array in mootools

Tags: javascript, object, mootools

I have this piece of code:

```
['design','finish','grills'].each(function(type) {

    this.json.type.each(function(obj, index) {
        console.log(obj);
    });

}.bind(this));
```

And get this error:

```
this.json.type is undefined
```

How do I go about making `type` a valid thing to do an `each` on?
I am not sure of the correct terminology so any help with this will also be a bonus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
['design','finish','grills'].each(function(type) {

    this.json[type].each(function(obj, index) {
        console.log(obj);
    });

}.bind(this));
```

Currently your code is trying to find an attribute named `type` rather then the key which the variable contains.

Answer (score 0):

I  figured it out:

```
['design','finish','grills'].each(function(type) {

    this.json[type].each(function(obj, index) {
        console.log(obj);
    });

}.bind(this));
```